# Nginx: Replacing response text, with text from another text/JSON file

Tags: json, nginx

In the following HTML file served via NGINX:

```
<html>
    <body>Today is {{day}}</body>
</html>
```

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "year": "2015",
    "month": "July",
    "day": "Thursday"
}
```

I would like the output to be modified by NGINX to the following:

```
<html>
    <body>Today is Thursday</body>
</html>
```

I have looked into searching the response text via regex and replacing it, using the module: NGINX using: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

The question is, how do I read the JSON file located on the same server as NGINX, and map the replacements?

P.s.: If needed, I can make amends to using plain text file for the mappings, instead of JSON file.

Comment: It looks like to a nginx's job. You could try lua or perl module though.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference for other searchers, you can use the [SSI module of NGINX](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) for this.

You would need the variables in your NGINX config:

```
location = /today.html {
  ssi on;
  set $year '2015';
  set $month 'July';
  set $day 'Thursday';
  root /var/www/default;
}
```

And in the template file (`/var/www/default/today.html`):

```
<html>
  <body>Today is <!--# echo var="day" --></body>
</html>
```

> I can make amends to using plain text file for the mappings, instead of JSON file

I don't now if you can do this via JSON, but it should be possible with plain text files. You can include the plain text file in the template ([docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/dynamic_ssi/)):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!--# include file="day.txt" -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Where `day.txt` should contain

```
Thursday
```

You can also include a script that return the current day, so you don't need to update `day.txt`.

Comment: how can we used ssi variables in js file?

Comment: @ZOthix, you can use it in any text based file. Just use `<!--# echo var="day" -->` in your JS for example.

Comment: i tried it didnt work, ended up making a html file and having script tags init :"D